# tkinter entry widget not updating

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've searched everywhere on the web but unfortunately no where did 
I find an answer to this question:

after setting a tkinter Entry() widget's textvariable to a textvariable.

the text variable does not update after I have typed text into the entry.

code below:

```
def saveFileName(self):
    if(self.save_file_name != ""):
        self.window.destroy()
        self.name_not_set = False
        print("saving...")
    else:
        print("notsaving...entry empty")
        pass
def cancel(self):
    self.name_not_set = False
    self.exit = True
    self.window.destroy()
    print("exiting...")
def askForFilename(self):
    self.window = tk.Tk()
    self.window.wm_title("enter a file name")
    label = Label(self.window,text="please enter a file name:").pack(side="top")
    entry = Entry(self.window,textvariable=self.save_file_name).pack()
    save = Button(self.window,text="save",command=self.saveFileName).pack()
    cancel = Button(self.window,text="cancel",command=self.cancel).pack()
    self.window.mainloop()
```

The necessary variables have been defined and these methods are part
of a class which is a tk.TK() instance.

[image: my attempt to enter a name :(]
[image: console log]
this problem is very bothersome
:( very sad :(

Thank you and merry christmas in advance!

Comment: Please show how you defined the variable.

Comment: Note that statements like `label = Label(self.window,text="please enter a file name:").pack(side="top")` will assign the result of calling `pack` to the variable named `label`, which can often cause problems (maybe yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textvariable associated with an Entry should be a `StringVar()`. I don't se any such declaration in your code.

```
self.save_file_name = StringVar()
```

To set and get the value of a `StringVar()` you must use the `set()` or `get()` method, eg.

```
def saveFileName(self):
    if(self.save_file_name.get() != ""):
        self.window.destroy()
        # etc, etc.
```

Also, don't create more than one instance of `Tk()` as in:

```
def askForFilename(self):
    self.window = tk.Tk()
```

Use `Toplevel()` instead. Or even better: use the tkinter filedialogs.

Comment: Thank you!
I did set the StringVar variable in the datafield. which I didn't include in my code above so sorry for the inclarity(if that's a word)
but the issue appears to be the second thing you mentioned.
I forgot to call .get() on the StringVar, :D